# Excel Small Function Returning only first Instances of Duplicates

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates

When I use Small/Large functions to sort data, I get duplicates returned, how do I no longer get duplicates? I have a large amount of data I am working with in an excel file - names of people with a plethora of variables to rank them. I am looking to find the top and bottom performers based on certain variables that I want to look at - some of these variables will have the same numbers - hence where the duplicates show up.

I have coded out a large function that sorts and seperates the data very well... until duplicate variable numbers are involved. Then the first row that has that respective duplicated variable is copied each time that duplicate varaible shows up. I want to pass over the duplicate and get the names for each person, regardless if the variable number is the same.

```
INDEX($BQ$35:$BQ$500,MATCH(1,INDEX(($CD$35:$CD$400=SMALL($CD$35:$CD$500,ROWS(W$552:W552)))*(COUNTIF(W$552:W552,$BQ$35:$BQ$500)=0),),0))
```

This code returns me list/table, but shows duplicates as the first instance of that duplicate. I want every instance to be shown.

```
Xing Dong Chen  -0.890
Weishen Deng    -0.140
Michael Wan 0.200
Jojo Gonzales   0.740
Neelkanth Mishra    0.910
Ridham Desai    1.310
Aarti Shah  1.860
Daniel Fineman  2.340
George Tharenou 2.520
Ritesh Samadhiya    3.000
Hak Bin Chua    3.410
Manjiang Cheng  3.500
Manjiang Cheng  3.500
Manjiang Cheng  3.500
Manjiang Cheng  3.500
Juliana Lee 3.800
Jody Santiago   4.040
Andrew Boak 4.250
Ray Farris Jr.  4.340
Pankaj Mataney  4.420
Sakthi Siva 4.580
```

There are four duplicates in this because the variable numbers are the same, however the people's names are different. I want each different name to be shown, not just the first duplicate.

Comment: Take a look at [Ranking Data in Lists](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/rank.aspx) at the late Chip Pearson's web site.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, that solved my issues! Put it as the answer so I can give you points, or however this works.

Comment: 2 things : you remove this question by [posting the answer youself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) . And you can also reward the answering party by upvoting thier other post (same result you'll give them some points).